# Login details are not saving in UIWebView in Xcode 9.4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to ask that I am making a UIWebView App in Xcode 9.4?

I didn't add any line of code in AppDelegate. I want to ask that how to implement save session time to keep user logged in on any website. Even if a user closes the app from task manager also...

This is my code in View Controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let swipeLeftRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(recognizer:)))
    let swipeRightRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(recognizer:)))
    swipeLeftRecognizer.direction = .left
    swipeRightRecognizer.direction = .right

    webView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeftRecognizer)
    webView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRightRecognizer)

    loadAddress()
    }

@objc private func handleSwipe(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if (recognizer.direction == .left) {
        if webView.canGoForward {
            webView.goForward()
        }
    }

    if (recognizer.direction == .right) {
        if webView.canGoBack {
            webView.goBack()
        }
    }
}

func loadAddress() {
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: "https://uims.cuchd.in/uims/")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)
    webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)

}

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ :UIWebView) {
    activity.startAnimating()
    NSLog("website is loading")

}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ :UIWebView){
    activity.stopAnimating()
    NSLog("website finished loading")
}

}
```

Please anyone, help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: See below answer of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `httpShouldHandleCookies = true`

```
let requestURL = NSURL(string: "https://uims.cuchd.in/uims/")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)
request.httpShouldHandleCookies = true
```

Even you should use `URL` and `URLRequest` directly instead of converting `NSURLRequest` to `URLRequest` & `NSURL` to `URL`

```
let url = URL(string: "https://uims.cuchd.in/uims/")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpShouldHandleCookies = true
```